# duplicity: Is it possible to create each increment based on last full and not last increment?

Tags: duplicity

Duplicity creates each increment on the top of chain of increments. 
I wonder if it's possible to create each subsequent increment like the first one - with full backup as its base. Is it feasible without existing files modification (no moving, no renaming increments)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible at the moment. I posted a [confirmation/feature request on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/duplicity/+question/664091). You can follow it for the confirmed details.